# How to point R to the correct version of curl when upgrading nfrom R 3.6 to R 4.0?

Tags: https, curl, r, rstudio

Full disclosure, I have already posted this same question on SO, but on advice am trying this forum instead!  I originally posted this issue several months ago in RStudio Community which helped narrow the problem but still no resolution (https://community.rstudio.com/t/https-protocol-error-when-upgrading-from-r-3-6-to-r-4-0/88234/2).

Around 2018, I installed RStudio Server (free edition) with R 3.6.0 on a CentOS 7 server following the instructions found here: (https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/rstudio-server-pro-0.98.507-admin-guide.pdf )

Everything has been working with no issues. Recently, I've needed to upgrade the version of R, and have installed R 4.0.0 following the instructions here: (https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/ )

After installation, package installation on command line or in the RStudio IDE threw the following error:

```
Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I checked libcurlVersion() which returned:

```
[1] "7.47.0"
attr(,"ssl_version")
[1] "none"
attr(,"libssh_version")
[1] ""
attr(,"protocols")
[1] "dict" "file" "ftp" "gopher" "http" "imap" "pop3" "rtsp"
[9] "smtp" "telnet" "tftp"
```

So I can see https isn't listed in the protocols. There is another version of curl (7.73.0) on the computer (located in /usr/bin/curl) which does have https listed in its protocols, so I need to point R to this version instead. How can I point R to this version of curl?

Comment: You should configure RStudio to use libcurl 7.73.0 instead of 7.47.0.  It appears you can do that with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Ramhound.  I did some googling and went searching around for this variable and haven't had luck finding it on my system.  Is it an R or RStudio environmental variable?  Do you maybe have a reference you can direct me to where I can learn more?  Thanks!

Comment: I found reference to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` I believe from a Stack Overflow question

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, your hint led me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here was caused by installing R from precompiled libraries. To fix this I followed the instructions to install R from source (of course changing the URL in the curl step to the desired version of R):

https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/

Before running the compile step under "Build and install R" I set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib (which was the location of my libcurl 7.73.0) in the terminal, then followed the rest of the installation directions from there.

Finally, I edited the rserver.conf file to point to the new version of R, then restarted RStudio Sever and things are working fine.